# One large React prop vs. numerous smaller ones?

Tags: reactjs

I have one component that takes quite a bit of data. I have an option to either create 12 props to send down to the child component OR create an object with 12 keys and send the object down by itself.

I honestly see no difference trying one or the other, so I'm trying to get some input as to which setup is better for performance.

Comment: Are you using ES6?

Comment: @patrick Yes, I'm using ES6.

Comment: Create 12 props. Performance is not a concern here.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about the performance aspect of it until it was obviously an issue. Pre-optimisation can be a bit like falling down the rabbit hole.

Without knowing more about the actual object, I would say that 1 big object (which has 12 keys) would be much to worry about.

Instead, I would pass the object down as one prop and then use destructuring as necessary to any further children.

i.e:

`<ChildComponent largeObject={someObject} />`

and in `ChildComponent`:

`const { oneKey, twoKey, threeKey } = this.props.largeObject;`